# How do I check if Python is installed using a python script?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python setup script that will be converted to an executable file in windows using pyinstaller. Currently, I am trying to figure out how this script would check if python is installed on the system, if not, then it will go ahead & download the installation exe file from the python website.

My current code is as follows:

```
import subprocess, requests, platform

architecture = platform.uname()[4]

if architecture == 'AMD64':
    executable_file = "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.1/python-3.11.1-amd64.exe"
elif architecture == 'ARM64':
    executable_file = "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.1/python-3.11.1-arm64.exe"
r = requests.get(executable_file)
with open("python-3.11.1-amd64.exe",'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)


cmd = "python-3.11.1-amd64.exe"

returned_value = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
if returned_value == 1602:
    print("Installation Cancelled. Exitting.")
    quit()
print('returned value:', returned_value)
```

I currently have no idea how to check if python is installed so the exe will not be downloaded & ran by the script. So I would like some ideas on how I could go with this.

Comment: If the Python script runs, clearly Python is installed - how else would you expect the system to be able to run a Python script? Are you really asking how to check if you're on the appropriate version of Python? What problem are you really trying to solve here?

Comment: If python is **not** installed, what is going to run this script that downloads python?

Comment: If you might be in a situation where there is no Python installed and you want to install it prior to running your script, you should look into writing a batch file or PowerShell script (since you're on Windows).

Comment: The question states that the script is bundled using `pyinstaller`. I'm not familiar with Windows platform or with this library, but it seems that once bundled, the "script" (or more accurately - bundle) will run even if python is not installed on the system.

Comment: From what I do know with my experience on using pyinstaller, it does work like that.

Comment: The use-case is not entirely clear, and so even if there was a way (as I previously wrote, I'm not familiar with Windows), you may have to deal with cases where the installed python is actually python2, or lower than the version you expect (e.g. python3.7 installed, while you expect support for python3.11 features). Irrespective of versions, in the script above `requests` is used, so it bears the question if installed library versions are also an issue. [next comment..]

Comment: I recommend a different approach - installing your own python version (e.g. `%PROGRAMFILES%\ruler-python\`), where you can have more autonomy, and it will be much easier to check if it already exists. You will be able to control the version (and even upgrade if necessary) without worrying about breaking the user's own setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly execute the python command to see the output, or use the winreg module to obtain the installed applications of the local machine